# Sub-systems in game engines

Tags: scripting, cutscene

So here's the problem- I'm writing my own engine library, and it works fine with stuff like menus and the actual game screen. The thing is, I can't really figure out how to integrate something like an intro or dialogue preceding certain levels into this system. 
Let's look at another example- say I have a game-specific engine which gets a Level object and runs it. Engine would have its own collision and physics system, all hard coded. Now, what if at some point in a level, I want the player to enter a mini-game with different rules? How do I morph the Engine class to support these sub-systems without having to deal with their code all the time (as in: if(regular game) ... else if(mini game) ...)?

And what if I want an intro animation at the start of a level, and I want the player to be able to assume control of his character once the animation ends, do I implement the animation into the Engine class itself? Or maybe I need to run another class, CutScene, and when it ends, it calls Engine and starts the level? What if I want to add a dialogue system, where at the start of each level there's a short dialogue and the player can't control his character, and once it ends, he can? Would I then run the dialogue code inside the Engine code?

Maybe these sub-systems should all be scripted? I don't know anything about scripting, is it necessary for this kind of situation?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad and hard questions, there is a ton of ways to engineer this. But i would go with something like an interface for a "Game" module, and then code different games from there.
That way you could have an array of pointers to different classes which is different mini-games, but comes from the same pure virtual interface.

I think a good idea is to read some basic design patterns, and especially about modules and interfaces, and test some with that. In my opinion there is never a bad design for anything as long as you find it simple and use full to use it.

[Design patterns on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)
[Random design pattern on google](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Im not sure if thees are super good links, but what i saw they look like a good starting point for what you are asking.

Other than this, i think this is a super broad question and i cant even answer it all.
You have to google around and hope for some more good answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a good idea. I'm not sure how further design patterns could get me now, I've been reading about them for a while, and I'm planning on reading that book. That second link seems extremely useful as well.

Comment: unfortunately, engine designs is not something one can have in one day, it takes a while to get the hang of it, and only from fail & horror designs. so eventually, you will find a neat way!